# Given a number in base 10, get it in another base, where the other base may depend on multiple numbers

Tags: python, tuples

I have two series of numbers `a_i,b_i` which are all natural numbers and suppose for each i we have `a_i < b_i`. Then the number:
Integer `A= a_1 + a_2 b_1 + a_3 b_1 b_2 + ... + a_n b_1 ...b_(n-1)` can be uniquely written as `(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)`, this can for instance be done by taking `A` modulo `b_1`, this is `a_1`, then the result from `A//b_1` can be used to repeat this process, I have implemented it this way:

```
def int_dim_to_tuple(int_dim, dim_M):
    tup_dim = tuple()
    for (n,j) in enumerate(dim_M):
        tup_dim += (int_dim % j,)
        int_dim //= j
    return tup_dim
```

but I was wondering if there is some built in way to do this?

Comment: I think you're looking for  Numpy

Comment: it is similar to `base_repr` of numpy but this function can't do what I need here as it needs 1 base for all numbers, whilst I am dealing with different values for the different `b_i`

Comment: Please take a moment to read your title again. Do you really think that's a good title for your question?

Comment: As a mathematically inclined person I would say yes

Comment: If there is a module that would answer your need, I would also look first in Numpy like @cricket_007 suggested. On the other, if you do not find it maybe try to optimize your code by using mutable objects and/or generators for instance.